# Is possible to get userID or currentUser subcollection in Firestore with Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I need help to get userId in a subcollection in Firestore using Cloud Functions (Admin SDK). I tryed and get '**...must be a non-empty string or a non-empty array.**'

Assuming **db** is `const db = admin.firestore();`

```
const snapshot = await db
            .collection('clients')
            .doc() // <-- If put a manually userId string, it works.
            .collection('tokens')
            .get();

const tokens = snapshot.docs.map(token => token.id);
```

**Edit...**

This function return a token from user device.
In *.doc()*, if I put a userID manually, I can get the token that is recorded in the user's collection.

```
.doc('oM5f5BcwJmA43EuuuElLAUUe7q12') // Example entering uid manually
```

Part of code:

```
export const sendToDevice = functions.firestore
    .document('/clients/{clientId}/{warnings}/{warningId}')
    .onCreate(async snapshot => {

        const warning = snapshot.data();

        const snapshot = await db
            .collection('clients')
            .doc()                 // <-- This can't be left blank, 
            .collection('tokens')  // otherwise this function 
            .get();                // generates a new documentID.


        const tokens = snapshot.docs.map(token => token.id);
...
```

Database structure:

[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xACaQ.png)

Regards,
Binho

Comment: What type of function is this?

Comment: Welcome!!! Can you elaborate a little more what is a problem? What is a problem with getting userID string? Can you show your database structure?

Comment: Hello, thanks! I added more information about this function in post. I would like to know how do I get some UID or if is possible in the 'clients' collection.

Comment: It's not available in the function.  You will have to write the UID into a field in the document, and verify it with security rules to ensure it's correct.